# indexing custom Django model fields in wagtail

Tags: django, elasticsearch, wagtail, elasticsearch-py

We're using [Django MarkupField](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield) to store Markdown text and it works quite well.

However, when we try to index these fields in Wagtail we get serialization errors from Elasticsearch, like this:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 120, in handle
  self.update_backend(backend_name, schema_only=options.get('schema_only', False))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 87, in update_backend
  index.add_items(model, chunk)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 579, in add_items
  bulk(self.es, actions)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 195, in bulk
  for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 162, in streaming_bulk
  for bulk_actions in _chunk_actions(actions, chunk_size, max_chunk_bytes, client.transport.serializer):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 61, in _chunk_actions
  data = serializer.dumps(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py", line 50, in dumps
  raise SerializationError(data, e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'_partials': [<markupfield.fields.Markup object at 0x7faa6e238e80>, <markupfield.fields.Markup object at 0x7faa6dbc4da0>], 'pk': '1', 'research_interests': <markupfield.fields.Markup object at 0x7faa6e238e80>, 'bio': <markupfield.fields.Markup object at 0x7faa6dbc4da0>}, TypeError("Unable to serialize <markupfield.fields.Markup object at 0x7faa6e238e80> (type: <class 'markupfield.fields.Markup'>)",))
```

One workaround is to index callables that return `field.raw` but then we'd have to write one such callable for each and every Markdown field property we have in our models. I thought we could get around this by extending the field property (i.e., the django-markupfield `Markup` class that replaces the `MarkupField`) with a `get_searchable_content(value)` method but the serialization errors persist.

Does anyone have any tips for indexing custom Django fields in Wagtail + elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was putting the `get_searchable_content` in the wrong place, I thought it was needed in the `Markup` class but instead it needs to be placed on the Django model `Field` class itself. Wagtail will then pull the appropriate value to be indexed in elasticsearch (or any other search backend).

The most straightforward solution was to extend `MarkupField` with a custom Field class and add a [get_searchable_content(self, value)](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/1943d5a83c8a8a68345cf48bee9b739ad4001aad/wagtail/wagtailsearch/index.py#L206) that delegates its implementation to [MarkupField.get_prep_value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.get_prep_value).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. The best would be to create your own field in `elasticsearch-dsl`, see (0) for example, and use that for (de)serialization. Other option is to create your own `JSONSerializer` (1) subclass, and pass it in as `serializer=MyJSONSerializer()` in the `Elasticsearch` constructor, that can deal with `markupfield.fields.Markup` objects.

0 - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_document.py#L49-L58
1 - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/serializer.py#L24